# java script doesn't work in popup.js

Tags: javascript, popup, linkedin-api

i'm trying to build a google extension that fetches data from a linkedin profile such as name, education, skills. i have three files popup.js popup.html and manifest.json. My problem is while running my js code in a chrome's javascript console, it works perfectly but when putting it in my popup.js file it doesn't seem to work. Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.
here is the popup.js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}, function(tab) {
  

     //name 
     var name=$("#name").text();
     alert (name);
  //current-position
  var current-positionn=$("#headline").text(); 
  alert(current-position);

  //phone number
  var phone=$("#phone-view").text();
     alert (phone);
  //email 
  var address=$("#email").text();
     alert (address);
  //compétences
  var sk=$('span.endorse-item-name-text').text()  ; alert(sk);
  //expériences
  var exp=$('span.new-miniprofile-container').text()  ; alert(exp);
  
    
});

  }, false);
}, false);
```

popup.html

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Linkedin web scrapper</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>

 
</head>

<body>
<h1>Linkedin web scrapper</h1>
    <button id="checkPage">Add Profile</button>
 
</body>

</html>
```

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Linkedin web scrapper",
  "description": "This extension will fetch a linkedIn profile data",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "homepage_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/",
  "permissions": [
   "tabs" ,"activeTab", "https://www.linkedin.com/in/*"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a background.js to put the code that fetches the data and then send the data to the popup.js :

THIS IS THE BACKGROUND.JS

```
var nom=$("#name").text();
var current_position=$("#headline").text();
var phone=$("#phone-view").text();
var link=$("a.view-public-profile").text(); 

console.log("success");

// send data to server

window.open("http:// fetchinglocalhost:8080? name="+nom+"&position="+current_position+"&phone="+phone+"&link="+link+"");
```

As for the popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
  {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
           //executing script in the background.js
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "background.js"});
 }, false);
}, false);
```